# Obtener el tracking de una ruta OSRM

Tags: rutas

Necesito obtener el track de una ruta, pero solamente desde el origen al destino, sin la vuelta.

Realizo la siguiente petición:

```
json_file<-"http://router.project-osrm.org/trip/v1/driving/-5.81336,43.495596;-5.81779973,43.51087296?overview=full&geometries=geojson"

json_data <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(json_file), collapse=""))
```

Con este código obtengo el JSON resultado siguiente:

```
{  
   "code":"Ok",
   "waypoints":[  
      {  
         "waypoint_index":0,
         "trips_index":0,
         "hint":"F6RAiRykQInJAAAArQAAAAAAAABZDQAAZAAAAFcAAAAAAAAAqwYAACviAADrSqf_ubCXApBLp_-ssJcCAABvACcs_IU=",
         "location":[  
            -5.813525,
            43.495609
         ],
         "name":""
      },
      {  
         "waypoint_index":1,
         "trips_index":0,
         "hint":"tpSvhv___38AAAAACgAAACEAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAoAAAAhAAAACAAAACviAAD-Oaf_PeyXAjg6p_9Z7JcCAwDvEics_IU=",
         "location":[  
            -5.817858,
            43.510845
         ],
         "name":""
      }
   ],
   "trips":[  
      {  
         "legs":[  
            {  
               "steps":[  

               ],
               "weight":517.8,
               "distance":3963.8,
               "summary":"",
               "duration":433.7
            },
            {  
               "steps":[  

               ],
               "weight":467.3,
               "distance":3623.2,
               "summary":"",
               "duration":388.5
            }
         ],
         "weight_name":"routability",
         "geometry":{  
            "coordinates":[  
               [  
                  -5.813525,
                  43.495609
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813582,
                  43.495234
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813609,
                  43.494994
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813515,
                  43.495006
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813433,
                  43.49508
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813291,
                  43.495068
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813241,
                  43.4952
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813137,
                  43.495599
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813091,
                  43.495895
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813057,
                  43.496398
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813064,
                  43.49676
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813024,
                  43.496912
               ],
               [  
                  -5.812932,
                  43.497002
               ],
               [  
                  -5.812826,
                  43.497055
               ],
               [  
                  -5.812571,
                  43.497091
               ],
               [  
                  -5.812744,
                  43.497122
               ],
               [  
                  -5.81297,
                  43.497121
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813119,
                  43.497147
               ],
               [  
                  -5.81323,
                  43.497313
               ],
               [  
                  -5.81356,
                  43.497976
               ],
               [  
                  -5.81358,
                  43.498268
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813498,
                  43.498445
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813315,
                  43.49857
               ],
               [  
                  -5.812972,
                  43.498857
               ],
               [  
                  -5.812853,
                  43.499002
               ],
               [  
                  -5.81257,
                  43.49935
               ],
               [  
                  -5.812047,
                  43.49966
               ],
               [  
                  -5.811642,
                  43.500021
               ],
               [  
                  -5.811659,
                  43.500239
               ],
               [  
                  -5.81214,
                  43.500289
               ],
               [  
                  -5.812929,
                  43.500538
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813255,
                  43.500644
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813942,
                  43.500936
               ],
               [  
                  -5.814285,
                  43.501285
               ],
               [  
                  -5.814217,
                  43.501845
               ],
               [  
                  -5.814491,
                  43.502493
               ],
               [  
                  -5.814459,
                  43.502818
               ],
               [  
                  -5.814216,
                  43.503453
               ],
               [  
                  -5.814236,
                  43.503972
               ],
               [  
                  -5.814054,
                  43.504372
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813916,
                  43.504709
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813797,
                  43.50515
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813461,
                  43.505269
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813208,
                  43.505471
               ],
               [  
                  -5.812643,
                  43.505454
               ],
               [  
                  -5.812002,
                  43.505655
               ],
               [  
                  -5.811721,
                  43.506035
               ],
               [  
                  -5.810903,
                  43.506505
               ],
               [  
                  -5.810416,
                  43.506565
               ],
               [  
                  -5.809732,
                  43.506925
               ],
               [  
                  -5.809527,
                  43.507274
               ],
               [  
                  -5.809496,
                  43.507554
               ],
               [  
                  -5.809587,
                  43.507991
               ],
               [  
                  -5.810063,
                  43.508416
               ],
               [  
                  -5.810038,
                  43.508534
               ],
               [  
                  -5.809603,
                  43.508995
               ],
               [  
                  -5.809469,
                  43.509323
               ],
               [  
                  -5.810065,
                  43.509416
               ],
               [  
                  -5.810389,
                  43.509503
               ],
               [  
                  -5.811039,
                  43.509819
               ],
               [  
                  -5.8113,
                  43.509928
               ],
               [  
                  -5.812149,
                  43.51029
               ],
               [  
                  -5.814227,
                  43.511002
               ],
               [  
                  -5.814932,
                  43.511346
               ],
               [  
                  -5.815475,
                  43.511669
               ],
               [  
                  -5.815704,
                  43.511887
               ],
               [  
                  -5.815855,
                  43.512146
               ],
               [  
                  -5.815963,
                  43.512352
               ],
               [  
                  -5.816116,
                  43.512559
               ],
               [  
                  -5.816259,
                  43.512772
               ],
               [  
                  -5.816385,
                  43.513091
               ],
               [  
                  -5.816413,
                  43.513201
               ],
               [  
                  -5.816475,
                  43.513334
               ],
               [  
                  -5.817,
                  43.513943
               ],
               [  
                  -5.817601,
                  43.514557
               ],
               [  
                  -5.817723,
                  43.51465
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818087,
                  43.514912
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818106,
                  43.515006
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818155,
                  43.515095
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818265,
                  43.515198
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818363,
                  43.515251
               ],
               [  
                  -5.81848,
                  43.515289
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818677,
                  43.515308
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818903,
                  43.515265
               ],
               [  
                  -5.81907,
                  43.515172
               ],
               [  
                  -5.819174,
                  43.515051
               ],
               [  
                  -5.819212,
                  43.514863
               ],
               [  
                  -5.819155,
                  43.514716
               ],
               [  
                  -5.819016,
                  43.514588
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818865,
                  43.514521
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818737,
                  43.514506
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818719,
                  43.514492
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818668,
                  43.514456
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818621,
                  43.514413
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818562,
                  43.514341
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818525,
                  43.514219
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818546,
                  43.514107
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818695,
                  43.513693
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818817,
                  43.513358
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818938,
                  43.512981
               ],
               [  
                  -5.819012,
                  43.512652
               ],
               [  
                  -5.81902,
                  43.512404
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818985,
                  43.512079
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818939,
                  43.511861
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818843,
                  43.511606
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818779,
                  43.511463
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818616,
                  43.511103
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818512,
                  43.510873
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818513,
                  43.510776
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818565,
                  43.510686
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818576,
                  43.510587
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818563,
                  43.510529
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818536,
                  43.510476
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818508,
                  43.51044
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818475,
                  43.510407
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818413,
                  43.510364
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818342,
                  43.510331
               ],
               [  
                  -5.81826,
                  43.510308
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818135,
                  43.510297
               ],
               [  
                  -5.817993,
                  43.510317
               ],
               [  
                  -5.817919,
                  43.510343
               ],
               [  
                  -5.817855,
                  43.510378
               ],
               [  
                  -5.817766,
                  43.510459
               ],
               [  
                  -5.817721,
                  43.510549
               ],
               [  
                  -5.817719,
                  43.510661
               ],
               [  
                  -5.817773,
                  43.51077
               ],
               [  
                  -5.817858,
                  43.510845
               ],
               [  
                  -5.817858,
                  43.510845
               ],
               [  
                  -5.817969,
                  43.510897
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818077,
                  43.51092
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818098,
                  43.510922
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818223,
                  43.510919
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818309,
                  43.510956
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818413,
                  43.511015
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818499,
                  43.511119
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818699,
                  43.511572
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818827,
                  43.511918
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818856,
                  43.512063
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818894,
                  43.5123
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818899,
                  43.512461
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818895,
                  43.512552
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818828,
                  43.512929
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818717,
                  43.51327
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818618,
                  43.513548
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818432,
                  43.514073
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818406,
                  43.514197
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818406,
                  43.514309
               ],
               [  
                  -5.8184,
                  43.514417
               ],
               [  
                  -5.81835,
                  43.514563
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818237,
                  43.514621
               ],
               [  
                  -5.818146,
                  43.514716
               ],
               [  
                  -5.817723,
                  43.51465
               ],
               [  
                  -5.817601,
                  43.514557
               ],
               [  
                  -5.817,
                  43.513943
               ],
               [  
                  -5.816475,
                  43.513334
               ],
               [  
                  -5.816413,
                  43.513201
               ],
               [  
                  -5.816385,
                  43.513091
               ],
               [  
                  -5.816259,
                  43.512772
               ],
               [  
                  -5.816116,
                  43.512559
               ],
               [  
                  -5.815963,
                  43.512352
               ],
               [  
                  -5.815855,
                  43.512146
               ],
               [  
                  -5.815704,
                  43.511887
               ],
               [  
                  -5.815475,
                  43.511669
               ],
               [  
                  -5.814932,
                  43.511346
               ],
               [  
                  -5.814227,
                  43.511002
               ],
               [  
                  -5.812149,
                  43.51029
               ],
               [  
                  -5.8113,
                  43.509928
               ],
               [  
                  -5.811039,
                  43.509819
               ],
               [  
                  -5.810389,
                  43.509503
               ],
               [  
                  -5.810065,
                  43.509416
               ],
               [  
                  -5.809469,
                  43.509323
               ],
               [  
                  -5.809603,
                  43.508995
               ],
               [  
                  -5.810038,
                  43.508534
               ],
               [  
                  -5.810063,
                  43.508416
               ],
               [  
                  -5.809587,
                  43.507991
               ],
               [  
                  -5.809496,
                  43.507554
               ],
               [  
                  -5.809527,
                  43.507274
               ],
               [  
                  -5.809732,
                  43.506925
               ],
               [  
                  -5.810416,
                  43.506565
               ],
               [  
                  -5.810903,
                  43.506505
               ],
               [  
                  -5.811721,
                  43.506035
               ],
               [  
                  -5.812002,
                  43.505655
               ],
               [  
                  -5.812643,
                  43.505454
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813208,
                  43.505471
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813461,
                  43.505269
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813797,
                  43.50515
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813916,
                  43.504709
               ],
               [  
                  -5.814054,
                  43.504372
               ],
               [  
                  -5.814236,
                  43.503972
               ],
               [  
                  -5.814216,
                  43.503453
               ],
               [  
                  -5.814459,
                  43.502818
               ],
               [  
                  -5.814491,
                  43.502493
               ],
               [  
                  -5.814217,
                  43.501845
               ],
               [  
                  -5.814285,
                  43.501285
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813942,
                  43.500936
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813255,
                  43.500644
               ],
               [  
                  -5.812929,
                  43.500538
               ],
               [  
                  -5.81214,
                  43.500289
               ],
               [  
                  -5.811659,
                  43.500239
               ],
               [  
                  -5.811642,
                  43.500021
               ],
               [  
                  -5.812047,
                  43.49966
               ],
               [  
                  -5.81257,
                  43.49935
               ],
               [  
                  -5.812853,
                  43.499002
               ],
               [  
                  -5.812972,
                  43.498857
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813315,
                  43.49857
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813498,
                  43.498445
               ],
               [  
                  -5.81358,
                  43.498268
               ],
               [  
                  -5.81356,
                  43.497976
               ],
               [  
                  -5.81323,
                  43.497313
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813119,
                  43.497147
               ],
               [  
                  -5.81297,
                  43.497121
               ],
               [  
                  -5.812744,
                  43.497122
               ],
               [  
                  -5.812571,
                  43.497091
               ],
               [  
                  -5.812826,
                  43.497055
               ],
               [  
                  -5.812932,
                  43.497002
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813024,
                  43.496912
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813064,
                  43.49676
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813057,
                  43.496398
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813091,
                  43.495895
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813137,
                  43.495599
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813241,
                  43.4952
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813291,
                  43.495068
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813433,
                  43.49508
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813447,
                  43.495174
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813522,
                  43.495217
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813549,
                  43.495233
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813582,
                  43.495234
               ],
               [  
                  -5.813525,
                  43.495609
               ]
            ],
            "type":"LineString"
         },
         "weight":985.1,
         "distance":7587,
         "duration":822.2
      }
   ]
}
```

Este resultado son las coordenadas del Origen-Destino-Origen, pero lo que trato de conseguir con las coordenadas del Origen-Destino. ¿Cómo puedo arreglar este problema?

Comment: ¿Has consultado la [documentación](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.10.0/api/?language=JavaScript#general-options)?

Comment: Si, la he consultado pero no encuentro la manera de que solo me devuelva la ida solamente y no la ida y vuelta.

Comment: Acabo de encontrar la solución, si se pone roundtrip=false solamente hace la ida.

Comment: Recuerda colocarlo como respuesta con el enlace de la documentación y aceptarla. Será de mucha ayuda a la comunidad.

Comment: @adamista por favor, ponlo como respuesta y acéptalo para que otros con el mismo problema sepan qué hacer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si pongo "roundtrip=false" ya puedo hacerlo correctamente:

```
json_file<-"http://router.project-osrm.org/trip/v1/driving/-5.81336,43.495596;-5.81779973,43.51087296?overview=full&geometries=geojson&roundtrip=false"

json_data <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(json_file), collapse=""))
```